# How to validate passwords with pam

Tags: bash, password, pam

I have got a bash script which asks for your password, and then needs to validate the password using pam, I have installed `libpam0g-dev` as I understand I need it for this, but how exactly do I go about validating the password using pam? And how does pam let me know whether the password is valid or not?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28812/how-do-i-write-a-test-for-system-login

Comment: Note that no matter what you set "minlen" to and no matter how many "credits" you give to your users, pam_cracklib will never let users pick passwords with less than six characters--this is a hard-coded internal minimum. http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html#:~:text=One%20point%20is%20still%20the,a%20hard%2Dcoded%20internal%20minimum

Answer (score 1):

Not bash, but you could use a Perl script in your bash script **:P**

First install `libauthen-pam-perl`

```
sudo apt-get install libauthen-pam-perl
```

After that create a new Perl script, eg. with the name `foo` …

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Authen::PAM;
use POSIX qw(ttyname);

$service = "login";
$username = $ARGV[0];
$password = $ARGV[1];
$tty_name = ttyname(fileno(STDIN));

sub my_conv_func {
  my @res;
  while ( @_ ) {
      my $code = shift;
      my $msg = shift;
      my $ans = "";

      $ans = $username if ($code == PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_ON() );
      $ans = $password if ($code == PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF() );

      push @res, (PAM_SUCCESS(),$ans);
  }
  push @res, PAM_SUCCESS();
  return @res;
}

ref($pamh = new Authen::PAM($service, $username, \&my_conv_func)) ||
       die "Error code $pamh during PAM init!";

$res = $pamh->pam_set_item(PAM_TTY(), $tty_name);
$res = $pamh->pam_authenticate;

if ($res == PAM_SUCCESS()) {
    printf ("%s\n","Success");
}
else {
    printf ("%s\n","Failure");
}
```

<sub>based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28812/107084) with some modifications</sub>

---

From `man foo` **;)**

```
NAME
   foo - password test

SYNOPSIS
   foo username password

DESCRIPTION
    coming soon

OPTIONS
    no options
```

---

*Example:*

```
$ sudo ./foo foo wWeErRt    # wrong password
Failure

$ sudo ./foo foo wWeErRtT   # correct password
Success
```

In your script:

```
some code

ret=$(foo "$username" "$password")

some code
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be bash, I just have to be able to write some sort of shell script that will at least give the password to PAM, and then get some sort of reply back from it, I mean how does it communicate with you? Exit codes or something?

Comment: I've changed the Perl script. Check for `Failure` or `Success`